# ¿Cómo puedo llamar codigo escrito en Python desde PHP en el backend?

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, backend

Me gustaría saber como podría hacer el backend con PHP y llamar a archivos que tenga de python para hacer ciertas cosas como analizar datos que cargue en una base de datos.

Comment: Supongo que PHP tenga opción para ejecutar cualquier comando del sistema operativo con algo como `system()` o similar. Puedes usar eso para ejecutar cualquier cosa, incluido Python. Deberías, eso sí, hacer que tu archivo Python deje los resultados por ejemplo en un fichero del que luego puedas leer con PHP.

Answer (score 0):

**shell_exec** es una función de PHP que te permite ejecutar comandos del OS vía shell  y retornar su salida en un string.

> Esto lo puedes utilizar para ejecutar scripts python de la siguiente manera

```
<?php 

// Use ls command to shell_exec 
// function 
$output = shell_exec('python archivo.py'); 

// Display output python
echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; 
?>
```